# Reporting Services - DateDiff function

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I am trying to find a way to obtain the last day of the previous month in an SSRS report that I am building (it will be in the report header), but I am running into errors that I have been unable to get around.

Normally in SQL I would use a

```
DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,0,DATEDIFF(mm,getdate(),0)))
```

or

```
DATEADD(mm,0,DATEDIFF(mm,getdate(),0))-1
```

So I tried to convert this to a VB version:

```
DATEADD(DateInterval.Month,0,DATEDIFF(DateIntelval.Month,NOW(),0))
```

but I keep gettings errors. I then tried running the functions seperately and found that the DateAdd was working, but the DateDiff was failing.

Could someone please give me some pointers on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: *Visual Studio* is an IDE, not a language. What actual language are you using (VBA, SQL, something else)? *I keep getting errors* is not a meaningful problem description. What *specific* errors are you getting? (Is it related to the obvious typo in `DateIntelval.Month` in the call to `DateDiff`?)

Comment: @KenWhite sorry about the typo, I typed all the above in without copying and pasting, so no, that was not the issue. 

Unfortunately I do not get a specific error message, it just shows an "#Error" in the place of the expression when I preview the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't recognize the DateInterval function. Try using this formula instead:

```
=dateadd("m",0,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I didn't realize that the DateInterval was not recognized. Thank you!